# Using PHP in XML with no file extensions

Tags: php, xml

This is a 2 part question

Part1
I have to generate XML files that check current status. I had thought this would be a simple task but its turning out not so easy.

For instance I have code like:

```
if ($xyz=='yes')
{
$xml='Dummy xml string 1';
}

else
{
echo 'Dummy xml string 2';
}
```

Now here is a second part of this challenge
as this is to emulate Apple AirScan/eSCL Protocol I need to be able to deliver these files when URLs like the following are called:

```
http://192.168.1.1/eSCL/ScannerStatus
http://192.168.1.1/eSCL/ScannerCapabilities
```

etc

None of which include any .php nor xml extension.

For testing I have generated files with those names 'ScannerStatus' , etc , with 'file_put_contents' however results seem to be a mixed bag as some files load in browser with "This xml file has no style information" at the top of page while other simply show as xml text with no understanding as to why they are different. This may be due in part to the following found in the start of some example headers I have gathered from actual sources.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

However testing with the Mopria eSCL (AirScan) android client the client seems to accept both xml formats. I can only see the difference loading them in a browser though.

Comment: Are you setting the content-type header?  Use F12 dev tools in your browser.  Also, for PHP you can use index.php, for example `/eSCL/ScannerCapabilities/index.php`

Comment: @Dave S have you worked with this protocol before? Will try using index.php

Comment: Not Mopria eSC, just XML, PHP, and content-types.

Comment: The mopria client for android appears to be eSCL

Comment: @Dave S the index.php is NOT loaded by default in fact I have tested various options to get index.php to load and none seem to work with Mopira at least. Many seem to work in a web browser. Wireshark is sowing "Moved" from http://ip/folder to http:/ip/folder/ with slash and the client never accepts the redirect. My head is spinning from the non-working  "no slash" options I found that none seem to work

Comment: Is the server apache and is mod-rewrite running?  rewrite rules can change a path to CGI variables, for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955596/url-directory-as-variable-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with modifying apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.xml -f
   RewriteRule (.*) $1.xml [L]
   </IfModule>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have also since added .htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
```